# XML to HTML Conversion using XSL but skip duplicates

Tags: html, xml, xslt

not new to HTML but I am new to XML to HTML via XSL (and the terminology).

I am currently converting thousands of old MathCAD files and the process spits out a xml file containing roughly the following (it changes from file to file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConversionLog Date="19/06/2020 16:16:36">
    <WorksheetData SourceVersion="13" Source="D:\test.xmcd" Destination="D:\test.mcdx" />
    <Worksheet SourceRegionCount="495" WorksheetIssueCount="0" RegionsWithIssueCount="61">
        <IssueGroup Category="Unsupported Formatting" Count="1">
            <ConversionIssue Count="1" Text="Font formatting (subscript) was lost during conversion." />
        </IssueGroup>
        <IssueGroup Category="Display Differences" Count="60">
            <ConversionIssue Count="60" Text="The display of this operator has changed from the source worksheet. The accuracy of the results is not affected." />
        </IssueGroup>
        <IssueGroup Category="Calculation Differences" Count="2">
            <ConversionIssue Count="2" Text="The conversion has changed the math font. Upon recalculation, check that your results have not changed." />
        </IssueGroup>
    </Worksheet>
</ConversionLog>
```

I have produced the following xsl to convert it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <table BORDER="1">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <br/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1 I would like to know how to amalgamate all the attributes under the IssueGroup element tag? (so that it is all in one table and I don't have a duplicate of the 'count' attribute if possible)

2 how do I add a small gap between the different tables as using a 
 tag adds a massive gap? Can i use the padding tag ?

thank you

[image: Format]

Comment: Can you show what your required output is? Which XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: @Sebastien I have now added a example format but i am open to suggestions as this was my first stab at it

Comment: Do you know the format of your elements beforehand of do you need to keep this generic?

Comment: @Sebastien I needed to try and keep it as generic as possible as I have thousands of files that need to be converted with thousands of log files and i don't know what possible combinations that there would be. looking at the 10 or so that i currently have Worksheetdata, Worksheet, IssueGroup and ConversionIssue all seem to be common if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do this.
This is way more verbose than what you had but it offers room for customization.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table BORDER="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ConversionLog">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="grey" colspan="2">General Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">Date</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Date"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="WorksheetData">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="grey" colspan="2">Worksheet Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">SourceVersion</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@SourceVersion"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">Source</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Source"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">Destination</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Destination"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Worksheet">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="grey" colspan="2">Worksheet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">SourceRegionCount</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@SourceRegionCount"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">WorksheetIssueCount</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@WorksheetIssueCount"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">RegionsWithoutIssueCount</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@RegionsWithIssueCount"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="IssueGroup">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::IssueGroup)">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="grey" colspan="2">Issues</td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="lightgrey" colspan="2">Issue <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::IssueGroup)+1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">Category</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Category"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">Count</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Count"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px" bgcolor="#9acd32">ConversionIssue Text</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ConversionIssue/@Text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9u/1

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance, Now I am starting to understand how to structure the XSL file